# WAF Rule to block all http/https traffic using Azure Application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, web-application-firewall

When configuring WAFs I'm used to configuring the lowest priority rule to block all inbound http/https traffic. I  then add higher priority allow rules to open up the access I require.

I cant see how I can create a "block all" rule in the Azure Application Gateway's WAF custom rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. this is how you can do this (apologies the config is in terraform format)

custom_rules {
name      = "blockAllPaths"
priority  = 90
rule_type = "MatchRule"

```
match_conditions {
  match_variables {
    variable_name = "RequestUri"
  }
  operator           = "BeginsWith"
  negation_condition = false
  match_values       = ["/"]
}

action = "Block"
```

}

Answer (score -1):

**There is no way to create a `"block all traffic"` rule in Azure Application Gateway's WAF, because it helps to keep your web app safe from common threats only**

> Azure WAF is a web application firewall that helps protect your web
> applications from common threats such as SQL injection, cross-site
> scripting, and other web exploits. You can define a WAF policy
> consisting of a combination of custom and managed rules to control
> access to your web applications.

Azure Application Gateway Web Application Firewall (WAF) v2 comes with a pre-configured, platform-managed ruleset that offers protection from many different types of attacks. If you're a WAF admin, you may want to write your own rules to augment the core rule set (CRS) rules. Your rules can either block or allow requested traffic based on matching criteria.

Plese refer this [*document*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/application-gateway-waf-faq) for what are the rule currently available for WAF. ***In the Document there is no rule for block all traffic.***

Please refer this [**document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/custom-waf-rules-overview) for more information about custome rule. Custome rule is just help you use more than one rule based on different condition (which provided in above document only).These rules hold a higher priority than the rest of the rules in the managed rule sets

Comment: The first document you reference relates to the owasp rule sets, not to custom rules which I'm referring.

Comment: Yes Correct. But in the second document you can see the same set of rules which is in Document1.

Comment: So, I managed to solve the problem. See my answer above